# Change connection string when install Outlook Add-In

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto, connection-string, outlook-addin

I have an outlook addin(created with VS 2010 and C#) that it's connected to a database server but I'm facing a problem, when I'm debugging my app I have the config file which contains the actual connection string that is used to connect to database, the problem is that this connection string could change and I need to allow the user to put his connection string when he is installing the addin, that means my installer needs to change the value of the connection string.

Does anyone know how to make that?

Comment: Could you post what you've done?

Comment: How are you installing your add-in? Are you using a **VS Setup Project**, **InstallShield**, etc?